# Send an object to a method, and return this object C#

Tags: c#, oop, optimization

I'm currently working with C#, but this question is the same with all OO languages, I think.

I have a method, located in my "ServersList" class. In this method, I fill a ServersList with Deserialization.

Here's the method :

```
public ServersList fillList(ServersList serversList)
{
    //ServersList serversList = new ServersList();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BusinessObjects.ServersList));

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Resources/XMLServers.xml"))
    {
        serversList = (BusinessObjects.ServersList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    return serversList;
}
```

I don't know if it's better to create a ServersList in Main.cs, call my method with this SereversList as parameter and return the result, or call the function without parameter and create the ServersList directly inside it (like I do in the commented line)

Sorry if my question seems dumb or something, I'm pretty new to OOP and I really don't know which method is the best. Thank you for your help !

Comment: You don't need parameter in this function. In any case, the change made in this parameter is invisible by caller.

Comment: [codereview.se] is probably a better fit for this question.

Comment: As Alex said, there is no need to pass the `serversList` reference into the method. It's actually a bad thing to do, because caller might assume that the parameter contents will be changed by the method. The hardcoded filename, however, is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't think the code you posted would even work because you did not use the `ref` keyword for the `serversList` parameter

Comment: @Ben - You are right, but that depends on how you define "work". The caller would have to use the returned value. The parameter is useless: the reference would not change without the `ref` or `out` keywords, and the incoming list will not be filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no purpose in passing in an empty list, since you don't use it's value anyway. It would only confuse future reader an maintainer, especially on the user side. And I would make it static too. Compare this:

```
var serversList = new ServersList();
serversList = serversList.fillList(serversList);
```

To this:

```
var serversList = ServersList.LoadFromResources("Resources/XMLServers.xml");
```

Personally, I would rather write it like this:

```
public static ServersList LoadList(string _FileName)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_FileName))
        {
            return (BusinessObjects.ServersList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

By the way, it would be a classic example of [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: Indeed, I tried my code, and I could use a static method no ? If I understood static method concept, I just write `ServersList srv = ServersList.fillList()` and I'll have my srv List populated with data. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes. Look at the method example I added below.

Comment: Yes, I saw your code example after I post my comment ;) Thank you, I will use this method !

Answer (score 0):

If you need it only inside the method, create and initialize it within a method. Object'll be held on heap anyway, while reference to it will be held either on a heap (while declared in a class) or on a stack (if declared within method body). It's irrelevant here.

There's absolutely no reason to pass a reference's copy to a method without intending to read from it and modify it inside.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this line:

```
serversList = (BusinessObjects.ServersList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

The method `Deserialize` already creates a new list and replaces the list you have. This renders the parameter useless and also the commented line.

My suggestion is to change the method to:

```
public ServersList CreateServersList();
```

And the implementation:

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BusinessObjects.ServersList));

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Resources/XMLServers.xml"))
    {
        return (BusinessObjects.ServersList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

This way the list created by the deserialization is directly returned to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Not only that you don't *need* to pass this as a parameter, but it's actually a very **bad idea**. It implies that the method is doing something with the initial list, possibly modifying its contents, while it's actually creating a completely **new instance** and returning it.

Consider this code, for example:

```
public string DoStuff(string text)
{
    text = "Something else";
    return text;
}
```

You can easily call this method without even using the return value:

```
var text = "My text";

// this compiles
DoStuff(text);

// but the original variable was not changed
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Consider, however, at least removing the hardcoded string and fetching it from a, say, config file:

```
public static ServersList LoadServersList()
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServersList));
    var configFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerListPath"];
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(configFile))
    {
        return (ServersList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understood that now. However, is it possible to change the content of the list ? In your example, is there a method to get "text" variable changed ? I don't know if your understand me, my english isn't very good.

Comment: @T2o: Either you pass it as a [`ref` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) (preferred), or get the new instance from the `XmlSerializer` and copy all properties into your existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

Befor call Deserialize in you'r method, serversList point on method parameter reserved memory but when made Deserialize, serversList point on new ServersList object that created in serializer.Deserialize() method. then you don't need to get him in function's parameter.